# getting history from zabbix with python api

Tags: python, scripting, zabbix

i have one question about getting history from zabbix with python.
I'm only start learn python, so please don't dislike) 
so, i have little script python, who get the host, who showing all items, and i try from this information get history for the one second, but then don't filter.

```
>>> from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI
>>> zapi = ZabbixAPI("http://192.168.55.128/zabbix")
>>> zapi.login("admin", "zabbix")
>>> for host in zapi.host.get(filter={'groupids': '9'}):
...     print host
>>>for item in zapi.item.get(filter={'host':'Zabbix server', 'name' : 'Processor load (5 min average per core)'}):
...     print item
>>> history = zapi.history.get({"itemid" : "23297","time_from":"2014-10-04 00:10:00", "time_till":"2014-10-04 00:10:01", "output":"extend" })
>>> print history
```

and after this, i have all items, and no filter time, why? help please.
P.S. 
what i must filter, so them return to me only the value (for the setting date)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In `time_from` and `time_till` parameters, try using a Unix timestamp, like so:

```
>>> history = zapi.history.get({"itemids":"23297", "time_from":"1412370600", "time_till":"1412370601", "output":"extend" })
>>> print history
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone else has had this issue but it's 2022 and after a whole week being frustrated the answer posted down is the only thing that has helped me AND ACTUALLY WORKED:

```py
history=zapi.history.get(hostids=['10333'],itemids[56411],time_from=1489420800,time_till=1489562140)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
history=zapi.history.get(hostids=['10333'],itemids=
[56411],time_from=1489420800,time_till=1489562140)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.