# Can not fetch the history data of memory when using zabbix api

Tags: python, zabbix

I was trying to get history data of `vm.memory.size[used], vm.memory.size[cached], vm.memory.size[buffers], vm.memory.size[total]` using `history.get` method, but it returned nothing.
I can get itemid with `item.get` call. The code is listed below.

```
import sys  
import time
import logging
from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI

stream = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
stream.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log = logging.getLogger('pyzabbix')
log.addHandler(stream)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 

zapi = ZabbixAPI(ZABBIX_SERVER)
zapi.login(user, passwd)  
# get itemid
items = zapi.item.get(output='extend', hostids=['10470', '10471', '10472', '10473'], search={'key_': 'vm.memory.size[used]'})  
history = zapi.history.get(output='extend', itemids=['83140', '83141', '83142', '83143'], history=0, time_from=time.time() - 3600, time_till=time.time(), sortfield='clock', sortorder='DESC')
```

history is an empty list `[]`, so how can I get the history data of memory?

Comment: time_till and time_from must be in timestamp. https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/api/reference/history/get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting history from zabbix with python api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183001/getting-history-from-zabbix-with-python-api)

Comment: time.time() returns the time in seconds as a floating point number, it's already in timestamp. @JoaoVitorino

Answer (score 0):

I have a python script to generate a custom report of zabbix and the timestamp works in this form.

```
Date_F = "04/10/2015"
Date_T = "07/10/2015"

Begin = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(Date_F, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())
End = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(Date_T, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple()
```